# How would I extract line/band that are parallel to each other from the attached image?

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to extract line/band from the attached image, the bands/lines are parallel to each other.

[image: source image is here]

The line would describe the amplitude of the of the curve that you observe in the image. I want the line points in an array of length equal to the width of the image, one point per column, an example

[image: plot of the output line].

I am looking for algorithm ideas:

1. I have tried column-wise summation and averaging, the are sensitive to noise.
2. I have tried cross-correlation of the first column with each column in the image, and using the location of the max in the correlation, I get decent results, but I want better results.
3. what I have in mind is like a line tracing robot, to pick out a single line or band and tracing from left to right in the image.

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29620/242

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32432902/2521214 for some ideas